# Spam items that can't be found in suggested edits review queue?

Tags: discussion, bug

The suggested edits queue showed me an edit that looked "community wiki" had created an empty answer, which was **two years later** replaced with spam by a user whose profile says "has not posted yet."

There were no links to help me get to the item in the Q/A list, but I found a question dated the same as the "community wiki" answer which did not contain the item in the review queue.  When I returned to the review queue, the "community wiki" original was no longer blank.

But my browser was showing the "busy" cursor and I couldn't get rid of it.  So I exited the browser and re-opened.  Now that item is no longer there, and instead there is **another** item that has a blank original.  Again, the original is by "community wiki" and the edit is by a different person than the other.

More concerning is that if I can't find the items, I can't flag them.  Both of them appear to be spam, one for an Indian tourism agency, and the second for a Swedish airline.  The only way the first could be a real answer is if the question is something like "What is IRCTC?"  And the second, if the question were "What is Air Leap?"

UPDATE: The second was by a user who did have other posts.  Also, both items were in the queue twice: first with a blank "community wiki" edited to say something, and the second with the "something" edited to say more. The second one had the tag "air-leap" which when clicked showed only one question about spanner wrench that did **not** have the answer being reviewed.  The first had the tag arctic which when clicked had five questions, none of them appearing to be related.  And all four still look like spam saying "IRCTC is …" and "Air Leap is …"

Comment: Care to add a link to the broken review you are mentioning?

Answer (score 1):

It is usual that when you leave an item in the review list you can not get back to it. And as the edits were not yet approved you could not find them searching the site.

I have run the review list myself and found the items you mentioned.

They were not spam, they were tag wikis, where the tag is described. And as in these cases it described a company, it may have looked like spam to you.

If you now search on Air Leap and IRCTC you should get the tag and the tag wiki, as the edits have been approved.